# Displaying Progress indicator based on the inputs called total steps,completed steps and step names

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

I am working on a scenario to display progress indicator as below:

[Progress Indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyGOf.jpg)

I am trying to display the progress indicator dynamically based on the inputs provided(which are totalSteps which are 5 in this case, stepsCompleted which are 3 in this case and the step names).
I dont have much experience into Javascript. I tried below but it is static and look and feel is not the same as that of image. Any help on this is appreciated. Thanks.

```css
/* Progress Tracker v2 */
    ol.progress[data-steps="2"] li { width: 49%; }
    ol.progress[data-steps="3"] li { width: 33%; }
    ol.progress[data-steps="4"] li { width: 24%; }
    ol.progress[data-steps="5"] li { width: 19%; }
    ol.progress[data-steps="6"] li { width: 16%; }
    ol.progress[data-steps="7"] li { width: 14%; }
    ol.progress[data-steps="8"] li { width: 12%; }
    ol.progress[data-steps="9"] li { width: 11%; }
    
    .progress {
        width: 100%;
        list-style: none;
        list-style-image: none;
        margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    .progress li {
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .progress .name {
        display: block;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        color: black;
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
    
    .progress .step {
        color: black;
        border: 3px solid silver;
        background-color: silver;
        border-radius: 50%;
        line-height: 1.2;
        width: 1.2em;
        height: 1.2em;
        display: inline-block;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    
    .progress .step span {
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
    
    .progress .active .name,
    .progress .active .step span {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .progress .step:before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        background-color: silver;
        height: 0.4em;
        width: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0.6em;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    
    .progress .step:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        background-color: silver;
        height: 0.4em;
        width: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0.6em;
        right: 0;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    
    .progress li:first-of-type .step:before {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .progress li:last-of-type .step:after {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .progress .done .step,
    .progress .done .step:before,
    .progress .done .step:after,
    .progress .active .step,
    .progress .active .step:before {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    
    .progress .done .step,
    .progress .active .step {
        border: 3px solid blue;
    }
```

```html
<!-- Progress Tracker v2 -->
    <ol class="progress" data-steps="4">
        <li class="done">
            <span class="name">Foo</span>
            <span class="step"><span>1</span></span>
        </li>
        <li class="done">
            <span class="name">Bar</span>
            <span class="step"><span>2</span></span>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
            <span class="name">Baz</span>
            <span class="step"><span>3</span></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="name">Quux</span>
            <span class="step"><span>4</span></span>
        </li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a javascript function that sets the progress bar to a given stage. The example below does just that. The stages are indexed from 0. I've also added an `id` attribute to find the progress bar in JS.

The CSS provides a pleasant animation as an example. It'd benefit from a custom `transition-timing-function` to make it snappier. Another improvement would be make the node color animated. You could time that to sync up with the line's animation with `transition-delay`.

The `march()` function simply animates the example for demonstration purposes.

```js
function setProgress(barId, activeStage) {
    var steps = document.getElementById(barId).children;
    // Iterating all children avoids referencing undefined objets when activeStage >= steps.length and also handles setting the progress bar back
    for (var i = 0; i < steps.length; i++) {
        if (i < activeStage) {
            steps[i].className = "done";
        } else if (i == activeStage) {
            steps[i].className = "active";
        } else {
            steps[i].className = "";
        }
        // Alternatively .classList.add("done") and .remove() others, if overwriting classlist is to be avoided
    }
}

function march() {
    setTimeout(setProgress, 3000, "test", 0);
    setTimeout(setProgress, 6000, "test", 1);
    setTimeout(setProgress, 9000, "test", 2);
    setTimeout(setProgress, 12000, "test", 3);
}
march();
setInterval(march, 15000);
```

```css
/* Progress Tracker v2 */
    ol.progress[data-steps="2"] li { width: 49%; }
    ol.progress[data-steps="3"] li { width: 33%; }
    ol.progress[data-steps="4"] li { width: 24%; }
    ol.progress[data-steps="5"] li { width: 19%; }
    ol.progress[data-steps="6"] li { width: 16%; }
    ol.progress[data-steps="7"] li { width: 14%; }
    ol.progress[data-steps="8"] li { width: 12%; }
    ol.progress[data-steps="9"] li { width: 11%; }
    
    .progress {
        width: 100%;
        list-style: none;
        list-style-image: none;
        margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    .progress li {
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    .progress .name,
    .progress .description {
        display: block;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        text-align: center;
        color: black;
        opacity: 0.3;
        
    }
    
    .progress .name {
        font-size: 1.5em;
        margin-top: 1em;
        margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    }
    
    .progress .step {
        border: 3px solid #b6b6b6;
        background-color: #b6b6b6;
        border-radius: 50%;
        line-height: 1.2;
        width: 1.2em;
        height: 1.2em;
        display: inline-block;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    
    .progress .step:before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        background-color: #b6b6b6;
        border: 3px transparent;
        height: 0.2em;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0.6em;
        left: -50%;
        z-index: -2;
    }
    
    .progress .step:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        background-color: #1876d5;
        border: 3px transparent;
        height: 0.35em;
        width: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0.55em;
        left: 50%;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    
    .progress li:first-of-type .step:before {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .progress li:last-of-type .step:after {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .progress .active .name,
    .progress .active .description,
    .progress .active .step {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .progress .active .step {
        background-color: #1996fd;
        border: 3px solid #1996fd;
    }
    
    .progress .done .step {
        background-color: #1876d5;
        border: 3px solid #1876d5;
    }
    
    .progress .done .step:after {
        width: 100%;
        transition: width 2s ease;
    }
```

```html
<!-- Progress Tracker v2 -->
    <ol class="progress" id="test" data-steps="4">
        <li class="done">
            <span class="step"></span>
            <span class="name">Step 1</span>
            <span class="description">Foo</span>
        </li>
        <li class="done">
            <span class="step"></span>
            <span class="name">Step 2</span>
            <span class="description">Bar</span>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
            <span class="step"></span>
            <span class="name">Step 3</span>
            <span class="description">Baz</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="step"></span>
            <span class="name">Step 4</span>
            <span class="description">Quux</span>
        </li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: Hi kgello, Thanks for your answer. Your answer was helpful but I am looking for the output similar to the one that I have attached in this post( Please click on Progress Indicator link in my post to access that). Could you please help me in that. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Reading your question I got the impression that you only need help with the JavaScript. Are you looking for answers improving the CSS as well?
Or, if you are in fact only looking for answers related to JS, please clarify how the *behaviour* of the desired output differs from the one in my answer.

Comment: Please see the edited code. I haven't addressed every difference compated to the base you provided, but feel free to ask for an explanation regarding any parts that you feel are not self-explanatory!